# Почему не работает ajax-запрос в laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Вот есть обычная форма:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <div class="uk-margin">
     <span class="uk-text-bold">Число:</span><input type="text" class="uk-input uk-form-width-small" name="bs">
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" name="user">
   <button id="put_bet" class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="button">Поставить</button>
</form>
```

Вот сам ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#put_bet").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
            url:'/ajax', //url в роуте
            type:'POST',
            data:{bs: 'cof_one'},
            success:function(data)
                {
                    $('.th-cof').html(data);
                },
            error: function(data)
                {
                    console.log('2');
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Вот route:

```
Route::post('/ajax','BetsController@store')->name('bets.store');
```

И вот код из контроллера:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $bet = new Bet();
        $bet->fill($input);
        if($bet->save()){
            Session::flash('store', 'Ваша ставка прошла!');
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
    }
```

Суть ajax'а, пользователь вводит в поле какое-либо число, жмет на кнопку, и должен срабатывать ajax код, который это число изменит на виденное пользователем. Если что... с ajax'ом+laravel впервые работаю, так что не судите строго.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А у тебя `Route::post('/ajax','BetsController@store')->name('bets.store');` прописан в **web.php** или в **api.php**? Если в **api.php**, то к роуту нужно обращаться `/api/ajax`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72374/discussion-on-answer-by-andrei-kazmirovich----ajax---lara).